# Delayed scrolling behavior in an app with scrolling "prominent top app bar" in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, material-design

Current unexpected behaviour:
[image: Current unexpected behaviour]

Required scrolling behaviour:
[image: Required scrolling behaviour]

**I’m experiencing some unexpected scrolling behaviour in an Android Kotlin app with a scrolling "prominent top app bar”. The desired behavior is for the whole contents of the inner fragment (with layout defined in fragment_trains.xml) to scroll as soon as the user scrolls down on that part of the screen.
The prominent top app bar starts scrolling immediately as intended. The unexpected scrolling behaviour is that there is a delay in the inner fragment contents scrolling. They don’t start scrolling until the prominent top app bar has completed scrolling and reached it’s “condensed” smaller size. How is it possible to resolve this issue? Solutions I have tried include adding focus tags to various parts of the layout, but haven’t been able to find any other answers related to this issue.
See layout XML, and screen recording showing the issue. The inner fragment should begin to scroll immediately rather than be delayed until the  "prominent top app bar” has rested in to it’s smaller position. Even if it’s not possible to provide a solution to directly fix this, I haven’t been able to find example of an app layout like this with material design with a scrolling "prominent top app bar” and bottom navigation bar and a fragment in between with a scrolling behaviour. Thanks.**

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    app:liftOnScroll="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    app:liftOnScrollTargetViewId="@id/nav_host_fragment">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="28dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="28dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryVariant"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Trains.TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Trains.TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_trains.xml:

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
<!-- Travel info section -->

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/text_travelinfoheader"
    style="@style/TrainMediumCaption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    />

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/travelinfocard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_travelinfoheader">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_travelinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="19dp" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<!-- Next trains section -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_nexttrainheader"
    style="@style/TrainMediumCaption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/travelinfocard" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/nextrains_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_nexttrainheader" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, with the scrolling behaviour, this code:

```xml
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

needs to be moved from the NestedScrollView element in the fragment_trains.xml file, to the fragment element in the activity_main.xml file. Here are the new xml layout files to fix this issue:

New activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:liftOnScrollTargetViewId="@id/nav_host_fragment"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="28dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="28dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryVariant"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Train.TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Train.TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                android:minHeight="80dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

New fragment_trains.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Travel info section -->

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/text_travelinfoheader"
            style="@style/TrainMediumCaption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

             />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/travelinfocard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_travelinfoheader">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_travelinfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="19dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <!-- Next trains section -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_nexttrainheader"
            style="@style/TrainMediumCaption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/travelinfocard" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/nextrains_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_nexttrainheader" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the result, with the correct scrolling behaviour:

[image: Correct scrolling behaviour]