# AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" with MotionLayout inside does not work

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-motionlayout

In this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-iii-47cd64d51a5) Nicolas Roard goes through the examples of how to use `MotionLayout` with `CoordinatorLayout`. Also in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#10) there is an example of `CoordinatorLayout` with `MotionLayout`.

In both examples the `AppBarLayout` has a fixed height and it works fine for those examples.

But in my case I need to have AppBar height to be variable depending on the size of the views inside MotionLayout. It turns out that, in my app, with **wrap_content** height AppBarLayout height is different between `start` and `end` states. And because of that, scrolling just breaks the whole AppBarLayout collapsed/expanded states and animations.

Is it possible to have smooth animation of `AppBarLayout` with **wrap_content** height but total freedom in `start` and `end` states of views in MotionLayout?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578135/delayed-scrolling-behavior-in-an-app-with-scrolling-prominent-top-app-bar-in-a

Comment: can you share screen shot of what you want

Comment: Any updates about your issue?