# Prominent Top App Bar Not working Properly

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to implement the this animated collapsed toolbar which is not working properly even in the coordinator layout.
Please give me the solution so that i can implement this.

I've uploaded the project on the github if you need anything else.

https://github.com/Mr-Akki-Jangir/MyNotes_android_application

Here is the Activity which has this layout.

```
package com.example.mynotes;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.example.mynotes.Fragments.AllNotesFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class GoogleSignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialButton loginBtn, logoutBtn, btn_to_signup, goto_register;
    SignInButton GoogleLoginButton;
    TextView name , email;
    CircleImageView profilepPic;

    String GoogleName, GoogleEmail;
    Uri GooglePicUrl;

    FragmentTransaction fm;

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.google_sign_in_layout);
}
```

Here is the layout file for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="22dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="28dp"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.CollapsingToolbar.Collapsed"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:toolbarId="@id/tool_bar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/main_screen_top_app_bar_menu"
                app:title="@string/appbarTitle"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/navigation_menu_icon_downloaded"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/glacier_mountain"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        app:itemIconSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_tint"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/icon_tint"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the result or what i am getting, and this activity or class is just a experimental class so once i am able to get the result what i want then i will implement this into Main Activity.

And one more thing why the app bar and the bottom navigation bar is going behind the status bar and soft buttons in the Coordinator layout

[image]

And here is what i want to achieve

[image]

I have followed the guide on Material.io

you tube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzuSo4Bkh-k&t=781s

this answser [Delayed scrolling behavior in an app with scrolling "prominent top app bar" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578135/delayed-scrolling-behavior-in-an-app-with-scrolling-prominent-top-app-bar-in-a)

But non of them work plase anyone give me right layout file so i can complete my project.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research i found the solution on my own.
The main reason that the top app bar overlapping behind the status bar due to three important attributes were true in my AppTheme and those are.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

so i changed them into

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Comment: Your "before" and "after" code snippets are the same... :)